# Redirect all subdomains and subdirectories to index page using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

I have a [Detroit iOS & Android Mobile App Development](https://thefirstprototype.com/mobile-app-development-detroit-ios-android.html) website that only has one web page : index.html.

The source code of the site is [here](http://github.com/saamerm/TFP).

Instead of showing a 404 error page, I want to redirect the user to thefirstprototype.com if they try to go anywhere else or try to put anything after.

For eg:

- mail.thefirstprototype.com takes the user to just thefirstprototype.com
- thefirstprototype.com/mail takes the user to just thefirstprototype.com

I know it's possible to do it using a `.htaccess` in the root folder, but I am just not sure how. There are a lot of tutorials showing how to do it between different domains, but nothing to my specific case. How do I do it?

Thanks

Edit1: Please note that I am not using any CMS like Wordpress. I am just plain FTP to push a static HTML, CSS, JS webpage to the hosting server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect non-canonical hostnames (eg. mail)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/ [R=302,L]

# Redirect 404 to root
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . / [R=302,L]
```

However, whether this catches requests for the `mail.` subdomain will depend on whether that subdomain points to the same place as your main domain. (For cPanel shared hosting, that is not necessarily the case.)

Change the 302 (temporary) redirect to 301 only once you have tested that this works OK - to avoid potential caching issues associated with 301 (permanent) redirects.

As an added bonus, you could redirect any direct requests for `index.html` back to the root. For example, add the following *between* the above two rule blocks:

```
# Remove "index.html" if requested directly
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=302,L]
```

The condition that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is to ensure we don't get a redirect-loop since mod_dir internally rewrites the request to `index.html`.

Comment: I've updated my answer just to add an optimisation (to prevent an unnecessary filesystem check after mod_dir has rewritten the URL) and to tidy the code a bit (you don't necessarily need to specify an absolute URL in the substitution string on subsequent rules, since this is checked in the first rule.)

Comment: Just to add, if you have any intention of adding more pages later, it may be preferable to keep the "Redirect 404 to root" as a 302 (temporary) redirect, since 301s are persistently cached by the browser.